# Bookshelves App

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Here's how it goes, I already have 3 apps, Now what I am trying to do is to make an app that will serve like a store where they can browse my apps and buy/download them inside the app (no iTunes link), then once downloaded, they can open/use it inside the app (no separate icon). Something like the magazine apps on Newsstand that let you download an app and store it inside the app.

Does in-app purchase has anything to do with it?If so, in which part should I start?

Comment: Could you rephrase what you're trying to do? (Specifically, what do you mean by "all my previous app[s]"? Will the new app contain old apps already on sale in the app store?)

Comment: @Luke I think he means that it would be like the iBooks app but for apps... He would write his own App Store app and would sell the content, or apps, as in-app purchases.

Comment: @nOrville yeah! something like that, like newsstand.

Comment: If you are going to submit this to the app store, then you will almost certainly be rejected.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have any newly download code with In App Purchases.

Answer (score 0):

You will absolutely be rejected for an app like this. The [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#functionality) say:

> **2.7** Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected
>
> **2.8** Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected